# Varying Line thickness using R (ggplot)

Tags: r, ggplot2, visualization

[image]

I want to create something like using ggplot where those 2 points are categorical values? So from the first point to second point the line width should increase.Also the idea what I have tried was placing a triangle between those 2 points where one node of the triangle at one point other 2 nodes of the triangle are near the other point. Any other ideas would be helpful.
I tried many ways like using gglink etc but didn't worked out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could check out `geom_link2` from the ggforce package, which will interpolate a range of line widths from the start to the end of a segment. Here we can use it to reproduce your image:

```r
library(ggforce)

ggplot(data.frame(x = c('A', 'B'), y = c(0, 0)), aes(x, y)) +
  geom_link2(aes(size = c(0, 1), group = 1), color = "#b4dc2a", n = 1000) +
  geom_point(size = 20) +
  theme_void() +
  scale_size(range = c(0, 12), guide = 'none')
```

[image]

---

**EDIT**

From looking at your edited question, it appears you want to create a *graph* from your data frame, which represents an edgelist. In this case, we can use `ggraph` with `geom_edge_link2`:

```r
library(ggraph)
library(tidygraph)

df %>%
  as_tbl_graph() %>%
  activate(edges) %>%
  tidygraph::filter(P > 0) %>%
  activate(nodes) %>%
  ggraph(layout = 'circle') +
  geom_node_text(aes(label = name), size = 8, 
                 nudge_x = c(0.4, 0, -0.2, -0.2, 0), 
                 nudge_y = c(0, 0.3, 0.3, -0.3, -0.3)) + 
  geom_edge_link2(aes(width = after_stat(index)), color = "#b4dc2a",
                  alpha = 0.5) +
  geom_node_point(size = 20)  +
  scale_edge_width(range = c(0, 15), guide = 'none') +
  coord_cartesian(xlim = c(-1.5, 1.5), ylim = c(-1.5, 1.5)) +
  theme_void()
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, that's possible @People. You would need to edit your question to include a sample data set as well as a sketch of how they should be laid out though.

Comment: @People that looks more like a graph than a plot of categorical values. Are you looking for a network graph?

Comment: @People The best way to get more help is to ask a new question. Stack is actually a better format for getting help than private e-mail communication.

Comment: @People I prefer not to use chat thanks. Please ask a new question, or if it is something straightforward I can try to give you advice in the comments.

Comment: @People that looks like you are simply not drawing with a very good graphics device. Perhaps try switching to ragg or cairo? You can `install.packages('ragg')`, then, in the RStudio menu, select tools, then Global Options, then in the 'General' page, select the Graphics tab. In the 'Backend' drop-down, select AGG (you may need to restart RStudio first). Your plots will look much, much better after this.

Comment: Is it possible to have multiple plots for the ggraph?

Comment: @People yes - you can create multiple graphs and stitch them together very easily with `patchwork`

Comment: but using patchwork means we have to add the plots together individually, right? I want to generate multiple plots together

Comment: @People do you mean multiple clusters on the same graph, or completely separate graphs from separate data frames? Experience tells me that to get the help you need here, you would be far better to post a new question with enough information to demonstrate what you are looking for, including reproducible data and perhaps a sketch of what you want. Text-only comments are pretty useless for anything other than minor clarifications.

Comment: I have edited the question with the dataset and the current code I'm using. May be you can delete your previous edits inorder to reduce the confusion.